# Best way to download large file in compact cf

Tags: ftp, compact-framework, download

Using Compact cf c# framework 2.
I have 700 jpeg files on my server.
Each file is 9kb.
I use ion.zip framework to zip up these files. (not expecting any compression just a way to group many files into 1 file for download).
I divide these 700 files into 7 zipped files. Each zip file contains 100 jpegs.
I use OpenNETCF library ftp to download these files.
As soon as the 1st file is downloaded I extract frame by frame (using the stream object of the ion.zip framework) to render an image on a picturebox 1 at a time using a timer that runs at 10fps.
If the next zip file in the series has not finished downloading I disable the timer and display a caption 'buffering'.
As soon as the next zip file has finished downloading I enable the timer and the 'video' footage continues.

My questions are:

1. Is it best to use a large buffer size in the ftp download process
   (like 5000) or should I be mindful of a disrupted connection because
   of wireless/gprs connectivity?
2. Is there a way to resume ftp download from where it was aborted?
3. Should I not use FTP in this scenario?
4. Should I group the zip files into larger batches - say 200 a piece
   instead of 100 and carry a greater risk of connectivity issues?
5. Should I lessen the group of zip files to say 50 a piece and incur
   more ftp requests?

Code is available for me to upload but it is really the architecture I am interested in.

Thanks

Comment: FTP should guarantee your data, so it should resume where it was disrupted ...I'd think! UDP will send data faster, but there is no guarantee. Think of it more like watching a Live TV broadcast: If you get static, data is lost until the signal returns. I want to see how this gets answered, though.

Comment: @jp2code hi< i am using compact CF so I will have to code it for tcp/udp. I will post back here with my results. Thanks